# C++ Using files not working beginners

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#‎include‬ <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream buckyFile;
buckyFile.open("tuna.txt");
buckyFile << "Test";
}
```

After I run this, I get "Encoding Error" and "aggregate 'std::ofstream buckyFile' has incomplete type and cannot be defined|".

It's my first time using files in codeblocks, so don't judge me. I've been looking for a solution online, but I couldn't find.
Please help

Answer (score 3):

If you cut and paste that exact given code into Visual Studio (one defaulting to code page 1252 - if you're on another code page, it may be more forgiving) and try to save it, you'll get a clue:

> Some Unicode characters in this file could not be saved in the current codepage.

So, there's obviously something in the file itself which is causing an issue. One other clue will be the fact that, while the first `#include` is correctly colour-rendered in Visual Studio (and in the Stack Overflow code snippet), the second is not. This seems to indicate that Visual Studio itself is having trouble interpreting the line despite it being seemingly okay.

This sort of thing is usually caused by the presence of "funny" Unicode code points such as the non-breaking or zero-width spaces, or characters that *look* like regular Latin ones but may in fact be Greek or Cyrillic (or others).

So, copying that line into [a page that interprets Unicode strings](http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=%23%E2%80%8Einclude%E2%80%AC%20%3Cfstream%3E) turns up the following code points:

```
0023   NUMBER SIGN
200E * LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
0069   LATIN SMALL LETTER I
006E   LATIN SMALL LETTER N
0063   LATIN SMALL LETTER C
006C   LATIN SMALL LETTER L
0075   LATIN SMALL LETTER U
0064   LATIN SMALL LETTER D
0065   LATIN SMALL LETTER E
202C * POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING
0020   SPACE
003C   LESS-THAN SIGN
0066   LATIN SMALL LETTER F
0073   LATIN SMALL LETTER S
0074   LATIN SMALL LETTER T
0072   LATIN SMALL LETTER R
0065   LATIN SMALL LETTER E
0061   LATIN SMALL LETTER A
006D   LATIN SMALL LETTER M
003E   GREATER-THAN SIGN
```

I've marked the problematic code points with an asterisk `∗` to make it clearer what's happening. It's likley the line was copy-pasted from a web page that had those directional formatting control characters in it.

Hence the line itself is causing the encoding error you're seeing. The *other* error (incomplete type) is no doubt caused by the fact that the *first* error is preventing the `fstream` header from actually being included.

The solution is fairly simple, just retype the line underneath the current one and delete the original.

---

Bonus karma to anyone who can find the Easter Egg in the above post :-)

Comment: There's also a missing header.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit wins the prize. I thought it would be harder than that. Perhaps I'm less clever than I thought :-)

Comment: No power in the 'verse can stop me.